# CentOS / PostgreSQL. How to keep connections open?

Tags: centos, postgresql

I would like to keep connections open on PostgreSQL for N time.

I am not having problems keeping PostgreSQL itself open. The issue is that when the connection is idle for a few minutes, the connection from PgAdmin, LibreOffice Base, MS Access, etc, closes down. I then have to reconnect to the server or, in the case of LO, restart the entire program and re-open the tables I'd like to use.

The setup is:
CentOS 7
PostgreSQL Server 9.3
Hosted on Digital Ocean

I've searched high and low for a solution, but none of them sound relevant to my situation.

Thank you.

Comment: That's a valid question. I tried searching for answers but none of them are relevant. Answers I've found include running crons, which don't make sense. Aside from basic things like searching for configs or changing configs, I haven't found anything that would appear to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're behind a NAT router or other connection-tracking system with a short timeout. If so, you will need to [enable TCP Keepalives](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE) in the PostgreSQL server per this docs link, in the operating system, or in the client applications.

Comment: Ugh. I looked so hard for variations of "keepalive" and kept on missing the mark. Took a few tries to get the configs right, but it appears to be working as promised. Thanks a mil.